# Run tomcat in eclipse using maven build

Tags: eclipse, maven, tomcat

Is is possible to configure  tomcat server in Eclipse , such that it will use WAR  file, built by Maven, not by Eclipse

Comment: What is the difference in your eclipse build and maven build war files?

Comment: To answer your question precisely: Sure it's possible. If you're interested in details, maybe you should ask about these :)